# How can I get Perl to give a warning message when a certain package/tag is imported?

Tags: perl, import, package, warnings

I have a package that I just made and I have an "old-mode" that basically makes it work like it worked before: importing everything into the current namespace.  One of the nice things about having this as a package is that we no longer have to do that.  Anyway, what I would like to do is have it so that whenever anyone does:

```
use Foo qw(:oldmode);
```

I throw a warning that this is deprecated and that they should either import only what they need or just access functions with Foo->fun();

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, as you specifically state that you want to alarm in the cases of `use Mod qw<:oldmode>;` This works better:

```
package Foo;
use base qw<Exporter>;
use Carp qw<carp>;
...
sub import { 
    #if ( grep { $_ eq ':oldmode' } @_ ) { # Perl 5.8
    if ( @_ ~~ ':oldmode' ) {              # Perl 5.10 
        carp( 'import called with :oldmode!' );
    }
    goto &{Exporter->can( 'import' )};
}
```

Thanks to Frew, for mentioning the Perl 5.10 smart match syntax. I'm learning all the ways to work Perl 5.10 into my code.

**Note:** the standard way to use exporter in an import sub is to either manipulate `$Exporter::ExportLevel` or to call `Foo->export_to_level( 1, @_ );` But I like the way above. It's quicker and, I think, simpler.

Comment: Well really you did the same thing is moritz except specified the if statement, right?  I mean, if I put if (@_ ~~ ':oldmode') {carp 'blah';} in his it would be the same right?

Answer (score 12):

You write your own `sub import` in `package Foo` that will get called with the parameter list from `use Foo`.

An example:

```
package Foo;
use Exporter;

sub import {
    warn "called with paramters '@_'";

    # do the real import work
    goto &{Exporter->can('import')};
}
```

So in sub `import` you can search the argument list for the deprecated tag, and then throw a warning.

*Update*: As Axeman points out, you should call `goto &{Exporter->can('import')}`. This form of goto replaces the current subroutine call on the stack, preserving the current arguments (if any). That's needed because Exporter's import() method will export to its caller's namespace.